# results duplicate when cloning table jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server

As the title implies.

Here is my codes

this is for the jquery for the reserve:

```
function reserve() {
var rows = $('#tbodyMainTable tr');
copyTable = $('#view2 tbody');

rows.click(function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
        cloneRow = row.clone();

    cloneRow.children('td:last-child').html('<input type="submit" value="Delete" style="font-size: 12px; width: 100px;" class="delete">');

    copyTable.append(cloneRow);

    row.prevAll().hide();
});
copyTable.on('click', '.delete', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
})
```

}

Code for cloning

```
function loadSched() {
trial();
var originID = $('#cboOrigin option:selected').val();
var desID = $('#cboDestination option:selected').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: pageUrl + "/loadSched",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var cells = eval("(" + response.d + ")");
        $('#tbodyMainTable').empty();


        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {

            var d = $('#txtDatePicker').val();
            var c =  cells[i].shortDate


            if (d == c && originID == cells[i].OriginDesc && desID == cells[i].DestinationDesc) {

                $('#tbodyMainTable').append('<tr>'

                    + '<td>' + cells[i].FerryNameDesc + '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + cells[i].AccomodationDesc + '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + cells[i].ETDDesc + '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + cells[i].ETADesc + '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + cells[i].TripDesc + '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + cells[i].FareDesc + '</td>'
                    + '<td><input type="button" value="Book Ticket" style="font-size: 12px; width: 100px;" onclick="reserve();" /></td>'
                    + '</tr>');


            }


        }

    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    },
    complete: function () {
    }
});
```

};

HTML Code

```
 <div class="input-control text" data-role="input" style="width:300px">
        <button class="button"><span class="mif-paper-plane place-right"></span></button>
        <span>
            <select id="cboDestination" class="cboDestination"></select>
        </span>

    </div>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div style="width:300px" class="input-control text" data-role="datepicker" id="datepicker" data-date="1972-12-21" data-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
        <input type="text" id="txtDatePicker" placeholder="Select date..." onchange="loadSched();">
        <button class="button"><span class="mif-calendar" id="txtDatePicker"></span></button>
    </div>

    <div id="tblhide" >
        <h2> Available Trips</h2>
        <div class="flex-grid demo-grid">
            <div class="row">
                <table class="table hovered cell-hovered border bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <th class="sortable-column fg-white bg-lighterBlue">Ferry Name</th>
                            <th class="sortable-column fg-white bg-lighterBlue">Accomodation</th>
                            <th class="sortable-column fg-white bg-lighterBlue">Time of Departure</th>
                            <th class="sortable-column fg-white bg-lighterBlue">Time of Arrival</th>
                            <th class="sortable-column fg-white bg-lighterBlue">Trip</th>
                            <th class="sortable-column fg-white bg-lighterBlue">Fare</th>
                            <th class="sortable-column fg-white bg-lighterBlue">Book Ticket?</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody style="color:black" id="tbodyMainTable" class="tbodyMainTable" onload="trial();"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h2> Your selected Trips</h2>
        <div class="flex-grid demo-grid">
            <div class="row">
                <table class="table hovered cell-hovered border bordered" id="view2">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="sortable-column fg-white bg-lighterBlue">Ferry Name</th>
                            <th class="sortable-column fg-white bg-lighterBlue">Accomodation</th>
                            <th class="sortable-column fg-white bg-lighterBlue">Time of Departure</th>
                            <th class="sortable-column fg-white bg-lighterBlue">Time of Arrival</th>
                            <th class="sortable-column fg-white bg-lighterBlue">Trip</th>
                            <th class="sortable-column fg-white bg-lighterBlue">Fare</th>
                            <th class="sortable-column fg-white bg-lighterBlue">Remove</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody style="color:black" id="view2"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to view the result on the other table which is tbody view 2. the problem is it always clones once I click the button itself. it multiplies for the times I click the book now! please help and advise thanks!

UPDATE! For proper grammar, when I click the book ticket, it will call the command in reserve but once I click again the book ticket, it has 2 clones making it 3 rows instead of 2 in the other table. is there any way that the command can only run once so that it would just only acknowledge the single click single copy instead of single click copy then if clicked again become doubled? thank you.

Comment: sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Is it like: You are having many rows in table 1, and on clicking each row, you need to copy that row to table 2 [without coping any duplicate rows]?

Comment: yes sir you got it correctly @gjijo I just only want to copy the single item and it should not be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//click event for tr, who does not have 'cloned' as its class
$(document).on('click', '#tbl1 tbody tr:not(.cloned)', function() {
  //clone this row
  var tr = $(this).clone();
  //find the index
  var indx = $(this).index();
  //add the index as attribute to the cloned row
  tr.attr('index', indx);
  //add a class cloned, so that we can trigger the click event 
  //for all tr's who dont have this class
  $(this).addClass('cloned');
  tr.append('<td><input class="delRow" type="submit" value="delete" /><td>');
  $('#tbl2 tbody').append(tr);
});

//delete btn click event
$(document).on('click', '.delRow', function() {
  //find the index attribute
  var index = $(this).closest('tr').attr('index');
  //remove this row
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  //remove class 'cloned' so as to reenable the click event
  $('#tbl1 tbody').find('tr').eq(index).removeClass('cloned');
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>E</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br /><br />
<table id="tbl2">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In your case:

Inside `rows.click(function () {` event, you need to find the index

```
var indx = $(this).closest('tr').index()
```

add its as attribute to cloned `row`

```
row.attr('index', indx);
```

then, add some class(here i used cloned) to the clicked row

```
$(this).closest('tr').addClass('cloned');
```

And now the changes for `copyTable.on('click', '.delete', function (e) {`

find the index attribute :

```
var index = $(this).closest('tr').attr('index');
```

remove the cloned row as you did,

then remove the added class like

```
$('#tbodyMainTable tbody').find('tr').eq(index).removeClass('cloned');
```

ANd the code snippet should look like:

```
<input type="button" value="Book Ticket" style="font-size: 12px; width: 100px;" onclick="return reserve(this);" />
function reserve(elem) {
    var rows = $('#tbodyMainTable tr'),
    copyTable = $('#view2 tbody');
    var indx = $(elem).closest('tr').index()
    var row = $(elem).closest('tr').clone();
    row.attr('index', indx);
    var cloneRow = row.clone();
    $(elem).closest('tr').addClass('cloned');
    cloneRow.children('td:last-child').html('<input type="submit" value="Delete" style="font-size: 12px; width: 100px;" class="delete">');
    copyTable.append(cloneRow);
    row.prevAll().hide();
    return false;
}

<input type="submit" value="Delete" style="font-size: 12px; width: 100px;" onclick="return delete(this);">
function delete(elem) {
    var index = $(elem).closest('tr').attr('index');
    $(elem).closest('tr').remove();
    $('#tbodyMainTable tbody').find('tr').eq(index).removeClass('cloned');
    return false;
})
```

Comment: i'm just new in jquery and c#. my question is w/c fields should I change? should I change the document to the name of my table before the $? thanks .

Comment: No this is just a model. First please check whether you are looking for this functionality?

Comment: and also the tbl1 was generated from storedproc in sql server.  then the button was autocreated at the side together with the creation of the button. im so sorry im just new with this jquery and c#. i just want to learn more

Comment: yes i am looking for that kind of functionality. this is the exact function that i am looking for. sorry but no one is helping me here.

Comment: and another again. i can still reclick the letter here. for example i clicked a and i want to add another a it would copy again to the table itself. it is like adding to cart like that. im just new with this jquery and c# and asp.

Comment: it's logic is like ecommerce site like magento or abantecart where i can add multiple things inside my cart. the bottom table is the cart itself while the top one is the shelves of products.

Comment: @FallingInReverse: I've updated the answer including codes for your question. Please check and feel free to reply, in case you need more clarification or changes. Many people are here in SO for your help.

Comment: yes that's why I am here. Thanks to you guys that willing to help me unlike here in my place HAHA

Comment: I posted my answer kindly check if I am correct and educate me if I am wrong thank you!

Comment: @FallingInReverse I tried editing your answer, but it was not accepted. So I modified and accepted your edit in my answer itself. Please go threough it.

Comment: Hi, I tried to copy the codes to my solution but the problem still persists. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Am I correct that I added the onclick function inside this function? <input type="button" value="Book Ticket" style="font-size: 12px; width: 100px;" onclick="reserve();" />

Comment: sorry, you cant do it. as your click event is handled in `rows.click(function () {}`. I will modify the code, please check after some time.

Comment: sure @gjijo I really appreciate your help. I am learning so well to you. should I post my codes that adds the button on the master table?

Comment: I already posted the code at the top BTW the function is loadsched w/c is the code for fetching the data from database.

Comment: @FallingInReverse: Sorry, I was offline for a while. Could you please share the latest issue that you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

```
function reserve() {
    var rows = $('#tbodyMainTable tr'),
    copyTable = $('#view2 tbody');

    rows.click(function () {
        var indx = $(this).closest('tr').index()
        var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
        row.attr('index', indx);
        cloneRow = row.clone();
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('cloned');

        cloneRow.children('td:last-child').html('<input type="submit" value="Delete" style="font-size: 12px; width: 100px;" class="delete">');

        copyTable.append(cloneRow);

        row.prevAll().hide();
    });
    copyTable.on('click', '.delete', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var index = $(this).closest('tr').attr('index');
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        $('#tbodyMainTable tbody').find('tr').eq(index).removeClass('cloned');
    })
}
```

Comment: @gjijo Hi, I tried to copy the codes to my solution but the problem still persists. Am I missing something here?